# How to keep map state on device rotation?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a **nested fragment** that i would like to maintain the state when the device orientation changed.

It is something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPE7q.png]

I'm instantiate a mapView in the nested fragment and when the device is rotated the user must be in the same place where it was.
How can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i was making a mistake. 
I was calling the function *setRetainInstance(true)* on the fragment parent and i shouldn't.

After deleting that line, it was very simple to keep the map state on device orientation.
All i had to do was to save some values on *onSaveInstanceState* like this:

```
bundle.putDouble("lat", mMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude);
bundle.putDouble("lon", mMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
bundle.putFloat("zoom", mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
```

Then on onCreate, i restore the map state like this:

```
bundle.getDouble("lat");
bundle.getDouble("lon");
bundle.getDouble("zoom");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use it like this because `CameraPosition` class implements `Parcelable`:

1. save it

```
if (null != mMap) {
   outState.putParcelable("map_camera_position", mMap.getCameraPosition());
}
```

2. retrieve it in `onCreate()`

```
if (null != savedInstanceState) {
    mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("map_camera_position");
}
```

3. set it to move the camera

```
if (null != mCameraPosition) {
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
}
```